# Find all possible rational canonical forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Problem: Find all possible rational canonical forms of $4\times 4$ matrices $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $A^{3}=I$.

My Idea: Since $A^{3}=I$, we have $f(A)=0$ for $f(x)=x^3-1$. Then the minimal polynomial for $A$ divides $f(x)=x^3-1$. We have $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, so the invariant factors are $a_{1}(x)=x^{3}-1, a_{2}(x)=x^2+x+1, a_{3}(x)=x-1$. I know that the degree of the characteristic polynomial must be 4, and that the characteristic polynomial is the product of invariant factors:

$C_{A}(x)=(x-1)^{n}(x^{2}+x+1)^{m}(x^{3}-1)^{q}$. Keeping the degree 4 constraint in mind, we have the following possibilities for $C_{A}(x)$:

1. $C_{A}(x)=(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$
2. $C_{A}(x)=(x^3-1)(x-1)$
3. $C_{A}(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)$
4. $C_{A}(x)=(x^{2}+x+1)(x-1)(x-1)$

Do I have any errors in my logic? I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Numbers 2 and 4 in your list are the same polynomial. ;-)